# Interior Mutability in owner while immutability among share

Tags: rust

I am struggling with Rust Rc/RefCell. Essentially, I would like to mutate the state of T inside the struct which owns this data (Rc<Ref>). However I would also want to share this data (with immutability such as Rc) to external struct.

How do I achieve that?

```
pub struct A

pub struct B
{
    a : Rc<RefCell<A>>
}

pub struct C
{
    a : Rc<A>
}
```

Basically I am trying to store a reference of A in C but as you know in Rust you need to do 'a life time annotation which i cannot make it work in general.

And i do not want to pass the mutability of A into C.

Let me put similar code as of C++,

```
struct A;

struct B
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
}

struct C
{
    const A & a;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a MVE?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user2722968 please see sample code

Comment: @agoodname I rolled back [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72070021/5) since it only deleted content and made the question impossible to understand in my opinion. If you think I was wrong, you can bring it back, but please provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

It's self-contradictory to say that `C::a` is immutable while `B::a` is not, since `C` can be used to *observe the mutations.* I'm going to assume that you want `C` to provide *read-only* access to `A`. In that case, you *must* still specify `RefCell` in the type of `C::a` for *storage* purposes, but then you *don't expose the mutation part of the RefCell.* Just avoid having any public methods of C that expose the `RefCell` or the ability to get a `RefMut` from it, and you're done.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};

pub struct A;

pub struct B {
    a: Rc<RefCell<A>>,
}

pub struct C {
    a: Rc<RefCell<A>>,
}

impl B {
    // These are just simple examples; create whatever methods make sense for your situation
    pub fn replace(&self, a: A) {
        *self.a.borrow_mut() = a;
    }
    
    pub fn read(&self) -> Ref<'_, A> {
        self.a.borrow()
    }
    
    pub fn as_read_only(&self) -> C {
        C { a: self.a.clone() }
    }
}

impl C {
    // There are no mutation methods here so A cannot be mutated through C

    pub fn read(&self) -> Ref<'_, A> {
        self.a.borrow()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that is not what I need. I actually want A to be immutable inside C.

Comment: @agoodname Then I don't understand what you want. Your original code sample which had `Rc<A>` would do that, and it doesn't need any lifetimes. Can you edit your question to clarify what you want that you don't already have?

Comment: Hi, I have editted the question. Basically I would B to own A with the ability to mutate it. Then I want a const reference of A in C.

Comment: @agoodname You've provided example data structures but not said how you want them to _relate to each other_. **A Rust code sample which demonstrated the operations you want to be able to do to B and C, in sequence** would clarify things. I made a guess, and you said my guess was wrong, so please _expand_ your question's explanation. There is no direct translation from C++ to safe Rust, so we need information about the use case to be able to give useful answers.

Comment: Your solution is to allow B to mutate "a", which is good. However there is nothing to prevent C to mutate "a". Even though there is no mutation method in C to mutate "a", another dev can simply add a method in C to do the mutation no? Basically I want "a" to be read only in C (not just "expose read only")

Comment: @agoodname It is not possible to protect against modifying the code, in general. `a` is a private field of `C`, so it can't be accessed directly outside the module, and that's considered _enough_ — that's all that `std` has to prevent putting non-UTF-8 data in a `String`, for example.